# Unable to synchronize the clocks on a dual boot system

Tags: ubuntu, arch-linux, dual-boot, clock

A have a dual boot system: Ubuntu and Arch. Ubuntu was installed first. A while after installing Arch, I've set up its clock because it was 8 behind my current time zone (my time zone is gmt +8). I don't remember the actual command, something like `date --set "xxxxxx"`. However, I do remember that I specified the time zone during its installation (gmt +8, Hong Kong). And when I checked `sysclock` and it showed the real time in my time zone.

In Ubuntu the time zone remained the same - gmt +8. That being said, after setting up the clock in Arch I found out that the clock in Ubunutu was 8 hours behind the actual time. But! The time zone was still the same - gmt +8. So now in both systems the time zone is the same (Hong Kong) but the time is different in 8 hours. What's more that the clock in Ubuntu was changed by itself when I changed the clock in Arch.

What do I do about that?

`sudo hwclock --show` shows the same time on both systems.

Answer (score 4):

It sound slike one of your systems is configured to treat the hardware clock as localtime, while the other one treats it as UTC. [Ubuntu docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuTime) leave me to believe Ubuntu is UTC by default, so probably your Arch isn't. You can [check and set this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/time#Time_standard) by checking if

```
timedatectl status | grep local
```

returns anything, and set Arch to use UTC by saying

```
timedatectl set-local-rtc false
```

(Disclaimer: I run neither Arch nor Ubuntu and just googled tutorials for this.)